# Pasar array javascript por ajax

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

nesesito pasar dos array javascript

```
var distancias= [60.3,547,321];
var fechas = ['2019-05-14','2019-05-13','2019-05-12'];
```

por ajax

```
$.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"url",
        data:{
           'distancias': JSON.stringify(distancias),
           'fechas': JSON.stringify(fechas)
        },
        success:function(r){
           alert(r);
        }
     });
```

en el archivo php lo recibo de esta manera

grafico.php

```
foreach (json_decode($_POST['fechas']) as $value) {
  echo "<br>".$value;
  // no me lo ejecuta correctamente
}
// me imprime vacio

foreach (json_decode($_POST['distancias']) as $value) {
  echo "<br>".$value;
  // se ejecuta correctamente
}
// me imprime
// 60.3
// 547
// 321
```

segun lo que he notado que el array que tiene sólo números ya sea enteros o con decimales me lo recorre correctamente, ya cuando le añado un elemento de tipo string al array me tira el siguiente error

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in (ruta del archivo)

**¿cómo envío un array de tipo string por ajax?**

Comment: no es necesario el JSON.stringify , a menos que en tu servidor PHP hagas el JSON_encode, puedes eliminar eso y creo que te funcionara

Comment: Haz var_dump(json_decode($_POST['distancias']));die; a ver que te devuelve y ya sales de dudas.

Comment: ya lo hice y con el var_dump(json_decode($_POST['distancias'])) me devuelve el array que mandé, pero con el de fechas por ser elementos de string no me devuelve nada

Comment: Saca el var_dump a $_POST directamente

Comment: dice que es NULL y cuando cambio ese array por solo número me da todo el array con dicho números que le he enviado

Comment: no es necesario el JSON.stringfy!!, esta transformando el arreglo a string por eso tienes problemas

Comment: Si lo que dice @JackNavaRow es cierto, en tal caso enviaría bien si hicieses 'fechas': JSON.stringify({ fechas: fechas})

Comment: estimado JackNavaRow envie fechas que es el array que tiene string tal como esta sin JSON.strinify y me da error tambien

Comment: @KevinCastellanos he probado tu codigo y si me imprime los datos correctamente

Comment: ¿no te dio ningun problema con obtener los datos de fecha?  que es de tipo string

Comment: @JackNavaRow tu sugerencia de no usar JSON.stringify funcionó gracias por comentar con tus conocimientos

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cambia `type: "POST"` por `method: "POST"` a menos que estes usando una versión antigua de Jquery, de no ser así por default la información se envía por `GET`. Como te comentan todos en los comentarios, no es necesario `JSON.stringify` ya que rompes la codificación JSON por default. Agregué un poco de ES6 al objeto que se envía en `data` si la clave-valor se llaman igual, no hay necesidad de repetir el nombre

**Type**

> An alias for method. You should use type if you're using versions of
>   jQuery prior to 1.9.0.

Debería quedarte algo así

```
$.ajax({
        method:"POST",
        url:"url",
        data:{ distancias, fechas },
        success:function(r){
           alert(r);
        }
     });
```

Y tu PHP así

```
foreach ( $_POST['fechas'] as $value) {
  echo "<br>".$value;
}
```

Considero que es más limpio así tu código que estar codificando y decodificando información, a menos que las reglas de negocio dicten lo contrario (Lo dudo)

Comment: Gracias me funcionó a la perfección marcaré como respuesta aceptada.

Answer (score 0):

Todo depende de como lo estés haciendo, yo suelo hacerlo así:

```
var distancias = '60.3,547,321';
var fechas = '2019-05-14,2019-05-13,2019-05-12';

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "url",
    async:true,
    dataType: "html",                      
    data: ({
        distancias: distancias,
        fechas: fechas
    }),
    beforeSend: function() {
},
    success: function(html){
        console.log(html);
    },
    complete: function(data){           
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

en tu PHP:

```
$distancias = $_POST['distancias']; 
$fechas = $_POST['fechas']; 
$array_dis = explode(',', $distancias); //convertir en array un string
$array_fec = explode(',', $fechas);
$text = '';
for ($i=0; $i < count($array_dis) ; $i++) { 
  $text .= ' Hola '.$array_dis[$i].'<br> ';
} 
for ($i=0; $i < count($array_fec) ; $i++) { 
  $text .= ' FEC '.$array_fec[$i].'<br> ';
}
echo $text; exit();
```

Comment: cierto de esa manera tambien se puede solo que yo esos array los lleno dinamicamente, gracias por comentar tu solución